# Multi-device OpenCL/OpenGL context

Tags: opengl, opencl, gpu, cpu, openglcontext

I'm currently writing a smoke simulation in OpenCL where I use OpenGL (freeglut) to visualize the smoke.

My computer is a Asus Zenbook with a Intel i7 CPU and a Intel HD 4000 GPU which are both "recognized" (HD 4000 = CL_DEVICE_TYP_GPU & Intel i7 = CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU) by OpenCL and contained in my device list. Both devices supports "cl_khr_gl_sharing".

I'm setting up the OGL/OCL context together with its properties like this:

```
cl_context_properties props[] = 
{
    CL_GL_CONTEXT_KHR, (cl_context_properties)wglGetCurrentContext(), 
    CL_WGL_HDC_KHR,     (cl_context_properties)wglGetCurrentDC(), 
    CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, (cl_context_properties)m_platformID,
    NULL
};
cl_device_id devices[32];
size_t size;
clGetGLContextInfoKHR_fn clGetGLContextInfo = (clGetGLContextInfoKHR_fn)clGetExtensionFunctionAddressForPlatform(m_platformID, "clGetGLContextInfoKHR"); 
clGetGLContextInfo(props, CL_DEVICES_FOR_GL_CONTEXT_KHR, 32 * sizeof(cl_device_id), devices, &size);
cl_uint deviceCount = (cl_uint)(size/sizeof(cl_device_id));

cl_context cntxt = clCreateContext(props, deviceCount, devices, NULL, NULL, &status);
```

But the clCreateContext function returns -33 which is error code for "INVALID_DEVICE". In the code above my "devicecount" variable becomes equal to 2 which should imply that both devices are associable with the current GL context.

Creating the context works only when passing in either of the two devices **separately** and in these cases the simulation runs fine (though of course very slow on the CPU).

A similar question is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17956821/opencl-opengl-interop-with-multiple-gpus/) one and it has been answered but to be honest I don't really understand the answer.

So, my questions are:

Is it possible to create a shared context between OpenCL and OpenGL with **multiple** CL devices?

If so..

Is the method i'm using to create the context correct or is there another way of setting up a OCL/OGL context with more than one device?

Comment: But gl runs in a single device or some sli/crossfire setup. Can you enable that with those devices? Did you try software rendering with gl? Maybe there is something like very old games in times of T&L acceleration beggining.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik I have no clue how to enable sli/crossfire. I'm honestly not quite sure about what those setups are. I have not tried software rendering, how would that help or answer my question?

Comment: It might not be possible to create a Context with those 2 devices, as there might be some hardware limitations, hence the OpenCL driver is not allowing to create a context for them. Normally the context should be created, but it is not compulsory

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create context having one GL device and mulitple CL devices.
Each GL device can have interop with any of the CL device if the inter-gpu interop is supported by the corresponding vendor.